# Is there any difference between "spider-man" and "human spider"?

Tags: meaning, differences, semantics

I am trying to write a review of a text.

I am trying to understand the context of two phrases: "**spider-man**" and "**human spider**".

Do they mean different things?

Although these two words were used interchangeably in the movie "Spiderman" (2002), I have a feeling that, grammatically, "spider-man" means "a human with spider properties". On the other hand, "*human spider*" means "a spider with human properties".

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: In both cases it is a human being with spider properties. Spider in spider-man is an attributive adjective.

Comment: Is a con man a con that's like a man?  Is a salesman a sale that's like a man?

Comment: Spider-man could just be the guy who sells you your spiders .... Just like an oil-man sells oil ...

Comment: I'm quite sure that [Spider-Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman) would think there was a difference …

Comment: Compare: ice cream man, human ice cream.

Comment: Your definitions make unwarranted assumptions about the semantic role of the first element of a compound. Hamawand, in _Word Formation in Cognitive Grammar_, lists 12 semantic roles of the first element of a compound adjective, and I'm fairly sure I've added a thirteenth. I've checked that the categories also apply, in the main, to compound nouns. _One can't argue convincingly for the meaning of a compound using merely an arbitrary possible interpretation._ // 'The Spider Woman' was a popularisation of a related string by Conan Doyle, and no

Comment: doubt this portrayal informed the majority perception of the three subsequent generations, especially after the Rathbone version portrayal. The Spiderman comics and films have doubtless informed the perception of most people bothering to think about the compound since. And more recently, perhaps Cumberbatch's courtroom character analysis of Moriarty. // You need to check on the types of compounds (endocentric, exocentric, ...). Wikipedia is a good place to start your research.

Comment: "Human spider" is often used of people who climb tall buildings with minimal equipment in a spider-like fashion ([Sky News](https://news.sky.com/video/why-human-spider-puts-his-life-at-stake-11535401)); "Spider-man" is sometimes used similarly, but being a trademark it is often restricted to the Marvel superhero (a book about a wall-climber probably couldn't be called *The Spider-Man* for legal reasons). The climber [Alain Robert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Robert) was known by both names, which suggests there's no real difference.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Lol, hilarious

Comment: I'd love to know what professional context the OP was working in. I think it might have a significant relevance whether you're working in a comic book store, a circus, or for a steeplejack.

Answer (score 0):

‘Human *anything*’ tends to be human first (eg human dynamo, human torch).

Other combinations often go the other way (eg motor vehicle is a vehicle, tree kangaroo is a kangaroo, beach house is a house).

Comment: Of course there's *Human papillomavirus* as a counter example.

Comment: @Jim Well, yes. :)

Comment: And [human flea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_flea). But human is a proper adjective as well as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

No.

> The term *human spider* includes women. It is at least a tenable argument that the term *spider-man*
> does not.

Of course, traditionalists like myself would consider the word *man* can include *women*, e.g.

> [Man is the measure of all things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protagoras)

But the comic book character to which *Spiderman* refers, has a female counterpart, [*Spiderwoman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Jessica_Drew)). Admittedly this lacks the hyphenation of the question, but hyphenation seems to be a matter of style, so the average reader would infer a sexual difference.

Answer (score 0):

"Spiderman" is, of course, a proper noun, the name of the character. "Spider-man" would (like "human spider") be merely a description of the hero. Presumably, in the movie, you cannot tell if any uses would contain a hyphen (unless the subtitles clarify things), so it should be assumed that any use of "Spiderman" is referring to the character's name.

Comment: Unlike *Superman*, the comic-book character seems to be *Spider-Man*, not *Spiderman*.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, although I understand this is going rather awry from your distinct question on grammatical-context, the kenning phrase of:
"human-like spider", "an arachnidian human", a "spiderly man" or a "spider-like human" (humanoid), would befit a much more harmonious, poetically sounding rendition, if anyone ever wished to creatively write on such a basis, of a particular figure or man who seemed to possess uncanny qualities of a spider or visa-versa, and with a more easing certainty that the reader would not think of the Marvel superhero, but rather the distinct depiction of such a character.

P.S. once again, please pardon me for diverting away from your particular question but I thought I would write this down if anyone ever came on the sight, who desired to write a story and desired another opinion on the concept of wondering on the "spider-man" distinction of whether it connotates distinctly to a spider-like quality.